# Getting shared path in controller with Rails and Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I have an upload system that performs several conversion operations on uploaded files (needs the real file paths to do them) and then stores paths of the resulting files.

Those files will be accessed later to create a zip file (again real path needed)

The problem with Capistrano is obviously when I store the file path using `Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'designer_user_uploaded')` and then try to create my zip file like 10 days later and the release has changed, the stored file path no longer points to the correct location.

My directory is in the linked dirs for Capistrano. So the files are not lost but they just can't be retrieved anymore.

I'm not sure how I should handle this. I think it would be easy to solve by just doing something like `File.join(shared_path, 'public', 'uploads', 'designer_user_uploaded')` but I can't find how to get the shared path from controllers. Also this might not work in development.

I'm on Rails 4.2.6

```
 output_folder = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'designer_user_uploaded')
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(output_folder) unless File.directory?(output_folder)

          file_name = sanitize_filename(Time.now.to_s + "_" + SecureRandom.uuid)
          original_file_path = output_folder.join(change_file_extension(file_name, ext))
          designer_file_path = ext == '.ai' || ext == '.eps' ?
              output_folder.join(change_file_extension(file_name, '.svg')) : output_folder.join(change_file_extension(file_name, ext))

          if ext == '.ai' || ext == '.eps'
            copy_file(file.path, original_file_path)
            copy_file(svg_path, designer_file_path)

            @response[:original_file_path] = original_file_path
            @response[:designer_file_path] = designer_file_path
            @response[:file_name] = file_name + '.svg'
            @response[:file_type] = "svg"
            @response[:colors] = get_image_colors(original_file_path)

            # Store created file paths for future access
            @up = UserUpload.create(designer_path: designer_file_path, original_path: original_file_path)
            puts @up.id
            @response[:file_id] = @up.id
          else
            copy_file(file.path, designer_file_path)

            @response[:original_file_path] = nil
            @response[:designer_file_path] = designer_file_path
            @response[:file_name] = file_name + ext
            @response[:file_type] = ext == '.svg' ? 'svg' : "image"
            @response[:colors] = get_image_colors(designer_file_path)

            # Store created file path for future access
            @up = UserUpload.create(designer_path: designer_file_path)
            puts @up.id
            @response[:file_id] = @up.id
          end

          # Embroidery conversion
          is_embroidery = params[:is_embroidery].to_s.downcase == 'true'
          if is_embroidery && (ext == '.svg' || ext == '.ai' || ext == '.eps')

            embroidery_file_name = "embroidery_#{file_name}.svg"
            embroidery_path = output_folder.join(embroidery_file_name)

            Embroidery::EmbroideryConversionJob.perform_async(original_file_path, embroidery_path, @up)
            @response[:designer_file_path] = embroidery_path
            @response[:file_name] = embroidery_file_name
            @response[:file_type] = "embroidery"
          end

          @response[:output_url] = '/uploads/designer_user_uploaded/'
          file.close(true)
```